# Android ViewModel do not load data the first time it is called

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata

Im using the ViewModel to get the data necessary to setup a fragment. When I call get viewModel.getItems().observer{} it always return an empty list unless I change the device orientation or pause and resume the fragment.

```
class OnSaleListFragmentViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val items : MutableLiveData<List<Item>> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<List<Item>>().also {
            loadItems()
        }
    }

    private fun loadItems() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            getDataFromDAO()
        }
    }


    fun getItems() : LiveData<List<Item>> {
        return items
    }


    private suspend fun getDataFromDAO()  = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val dao : DAO = DAO.instance

        val data = async { dao.getItems() }

        try {
           items.postValue(data.await())
        } catch (e : Exception)  {
           items.postValue(listOf())
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't go into the exception branch?

Comment: Yes, no exception is raised

Comment: For some reason items.value is null the first time it is called

Comment: That makes sense, it's read on a background thread. Use `.observe`

Comment: In the fragment I do that in this way:
viewmodel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(myFragment::class.java)

        viewmodel.getItems().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            myAdapter.reload(it)
        })

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
private val items : MutableLiveData<List<Item>> by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<List<Item>>().also {
        loadItems()
    }
}
```

with

```
private val items = MutableLiveData<List<Item>>()
```

and call `loadItems()` from somewhere else